# Can I sync Ubuntu One contacts in Lubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, lubuntu, contacts

I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 and have contacts in Ubuntu-One, but don't know how to get them synced. The default mail client is Sylpheed, though any client would do.

Comment: Get Evolution Mail, download the Ubuntu One control panel, and get your contacts back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as downloading and install Ubuntu One and then get evolution to get your contacts back

Comment: I have followed your instructions, but as I would expect from this tutorial (https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-contacts-sync/) the 'CouchDB' contacts should but are not listed. (screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/screenshotqw.png/ )

Comment: From the CouchDB logs in my home folder (hidden: .cache/desktop-couch/) it seems like the installation was successful, only the servers are not responding.